# Meteor React how to use passed in params?

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

I have two params that I have passed but I am unsure how to use it in the following example. Please help if you can.

```
updater(layer, item){   
    this.setState({layer5: <img id="layer5" className="on-top img-responsive center-block" name="layer5" src="images\5.png" />});
}
```

So here is my code at the moment, what I would like to do is something like the following:

```
updater(layer, item){   
    this.setState({{layer}: <img id={layer} className="on-top img-responsive center-block" name={layer} src={item.src} />});
}
```

But this gives me a syntax error.

UPDATE:
After the changes I am getting the correct values passed in but the state is not updating for some reason:

```
    constructor(){
     super();   
         this.renderView = this.updater.bind(this);
         this.state = {
                 layer1: "1.png",
                 layer2: "",
                 layer3: ""
         };
    }


      updater(layer, item){   
            console.log(layer); //shows as "layer1"
            console.log(item);  // shows as "3.png"
            this.setState({layer: item});
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not store React components in your state. Instead, store the information required to do the rendering and actually render the components in the `render()` function:

```
updater(layer, item){   
    this.setState({
        layer5: {
            layer: layer,
            item: item
        }
    });
 }

 render() {
     var layer5 = (
         <img
             id={this.state.layer5.layer}
             className="on-top img-responsive center-block"
             name={this.state.layer5.layer}
             src={this.state.layer5.item}
          />
      )

      ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks see update: have changed it so only the image is used the rest is rendered in render, still have issue however

Comment: @sophia I think `{layer: item}` doesn't do what you think it does. In your example, it would result in the object `{layer: '3.png'}`, not `{layer1: '3.png'}`. Instead try something like this: `var newState = {}; newState[layer] = item; this.setState(newState);`